# FileNotFoundError with shared memory on Linux

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, shared-memory

I am trying to create a shared memory for my Python application, which should be used in the parent process and in another process that is spawned from that parent process. In most cases that works fine, however, sometimes I get the following stacktrace:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 110, in __setstate__
    self._semlock = _multiprocessing.SemLock._rebuild(*state)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/psm_47f7f5d7'
```

I want to emphasize that our code/application works fine in 99% of the time. We are spawning these new processes with new shared memory for each such process on a regular basis in our application (which is a server process, so it's running 24/7). Nearly all the time this works fine, only from time to time this error above is thrown, which then kills the whole application.

**Update:** I noticed that this problem occurs mainly when the application was running for a while already. When I start it up the creation of shared memory and spawning new processes works fine without this error.

The shared memory is created like this:

```py
# Spawn context for multiprocessing
_mp_spawn_ctxt = multiprocessing.get_context("spawn")
_mp_spawn_ctxt_pipe = _mp_spawn_ctxt.Pipe

# Create shared memory
mem_size = width * height * bpp
shared_mem = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=mem_size)
image = np.ndarray((height, width, bpp), dtype=np.uint8, buffer=shared_mem.buf)
parent_pipe, child_pipe = _mp_spawn_ctxt_pipe()
time.sleep(0.1)

# Spawn new process
# _CameraProcess is a custom class derived from _mp_spawn_ctxt.Process
proc = _CameraProcess(shared_mem, child_pipe)
proc.start()
```

Any ideas what could be the issue here?

Comment: Always after a similar amount of time running? My guess is actually hitting ulimit for semaphores or file handles... Interestingly, I can't see how this would be directly related to `shared_memory`, as the error is about sending a `Lock` to a new process, and `SharedMemory` instances have no locks. It is also definitely an attribute of your process instance (I assume you subclassed `Process` and some attr is or contains a `Lock`?) based on it failing at `self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)`. Maybe make sure nothing is keeping references to `Process`es that are no longer useful..

Comment: @Aaron Nope, not after the same amount of time, it happens "randomly". I have added some code to show more infos on what I am doing.

Comment: I'm curious if there's a bug somewhere in tracking the current context, and the `resource_tracker` is unlinking the name prematurely thinking it came from a forking context. Can you try setting `mp.set_start_method("spawn")` at the entrypoint of the program just after import?

Comment: @Aaron Problem with setting "spawn" method at the program entrypoint is that a) the place where I create the shared memory is within an external library, and b) the whole application is using Gunicorn as server framework and I don't want to interfere with that :(

Comment: Perhaps in some cases the parent process ends before the child is fully started ?

Comment: Are you able to identify which line is this one ? `File "<string>", line 1, in <module>`

Comment: Gunicorn definitely complicates this, and I think may be very important to what's going on here.. how are you running it? what type of workers are you using? etc.. If Gunicorn is only using threads however and not additional processes itself (and I'm not seeing documentation anywhere that workers are ever child processes, only threads or coroutines), setting spawn early on should not only be safe, but probably beneficial (not  a great idea to fork after threads exist, but spawn should be safe)

Comment: Reading into gunicorn, I'm a little concerned as well with how it uses signal handling to control workers, and that some of multiprocessing's resource tracking might not be run if a worker is killed un-gracefully for any reason.

Comment: @yairhoff Nope, the parent process is still running, that is for sure.

Comment: @Philippe I am curious about this line as well - but frankly I have no idea where this is coming from. Also the stack trace is not related to any parts of my code, as you can see, which also doesn't help (me) much to identify this issue.

Comment: @Aaron Well yes I might try to set the multiprocessing start method at the beginning of the application, need to experiment with that and Gunicorn. By the way I also added an "Update" to the original post.

Comment: @Matthias the `File "<string>", line 1, in <module>` is due to the (child) process being started with `python -c "command string to launch child process"` rather than running a file. The traceback therefore doesn't have a concrete source file to refer to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251242/discussion-between-aaron-and-matthias).

Comment: The error is coming from `sem_open(name, 0)`. The name looks properly formatted `'/psm_47f7f5d7'`. Either it really does not exist (the question is of course why? - I don't know).  Or there is a tiny chance that something is wrong with the '/dev/shm' Linux directory (it is a `tmpfs` filesystem and `glibc` relies on it)

Comment: Do you have a sense of how long this runs before this happens? Linux has a maximum of 1024 file descriptors open per process: [link](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/fs.html#file-max-file-nr)

Comment: @SamThomas The error would be different if we ran out of files: `E[N|M]FILE` vs `ENOENT`. I'm quite confident this is an issue with the lock being `unlink`ed too soon.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue in case, that more processes had access to the shared memory/object and one process did update the shared memory/object.

I solved these issues based on these steps:

- **I synchronized all operations** with shared memory/object via mutexes (see sample for multiprocessing usage [superfastpython](https://superfastpython.com/multiprocessing-mutex-lock-in-python/) or [protect shared resources](https://medium.com/swlh/protect-your-shared-resource-using-multiprocessing-locks-in-python-21fc90ad5af1)). Critical part of code are create, update, delete but also reading content of shared object/memory, because at the same time different process can do update of shared object/memory, etc.
- **I avoided libraries with only single thread** execution support

See sample code with synchronization:

```
def increase(sharedObj, lock):
    for i in range(100):
        time.sleep(0.01)
        lock.acquire()
        sharedObj = sharedObj + 1
        lock.release()

def decrease(sharedObj, lock):
    for i in range(100):
        time.sleep(0.001)
        lock.acquire()
        sharedObj = sharedObj - 1
        lock.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sharedObj = multiprocessing.Value ('i',1000)
    lock=multiprocessing.Lock()
    p1=multiprocessing.Process(target=increase, args=(sharedObj, lock))
    p2=multiprocessing.Process(target=decrease, args=(sharedObj, lock))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```