# Can't spawn background processes after the app was running for some time

Tags: python, multiprocessing

In our Python application we spawn some background processes when the program starts up. Then in some cases we need to shutdown one of them and some time later we want to re-start (= spawn) another background process again.

However, it seems that sometimes, when the application was running for some days already (it's a server application), then it cannot spawn another process. In this case we get the following error log at the call of `new_proc.start()`:

```
Jun 23 14:23:46 srv gunicorn[2717986]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jun 23 14:23:46 srv gunicorn[2717986]:   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
Jun 23 14:23:46 srv gunicorn[2717986]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
Jun 23 14:23:46 srv gunicorn[2717986]:     exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
Jun 23 14:23:46 srv gunicorn[2717986]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 126, in _main
Jun 23 14:23:46 srv gunicorn[2717986]:     self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
Jun 23 14:23:46 srv gunicorn[2717986]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 110, in __setstate__
Jun 23 14:23:46 srv gunicorn[2717986]:     self._semlock = _multiprocessing.SemLock._rebuild(*state)
Jun 23 14:23:46 srv gunicorn[2717986]: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

So apparently the Python multiprocessing module cannot create the file required for a semaphore (or something similar). When I then shutdown the whole application and restart it, then again all subprocesses can be spawned again. So it really seems to be related to the fact that the app was running for some days already ...

Any ideas what might be the issue here?

Comment: For fun, you might try setting [multiprocessing.set_start_method("fork")](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.set_start_method) or blocking main if you are on windows per: https://superfastpython.com/filenotfounderror-multiprocessing-python/

Comment: @JonSG I have to "spawn" the subprocess, because the parent process is quite heavy and contains all the business logic, DB access etc., I don't want to fork all that into the subprocesses.

Comment: Have you tried; https://stackoverflow.com/a/68052154/8658598 ? I think it's mentioned in the JonSG's comments too. Not a complete fix though.

Comment: @doneforaiur Yes but adding a `sleep()` did not help either.

Comment: While researching, I came across your old question; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75099888/filenotfounderror-with-shared-memory-on-linux and the error looks very similar. Apart from `ulimit`, what about disk usage?

Comment: My guess is that the child process is trying to access a semaphore that for some reason has been unlinked by the parent, or maybe even garbage collected. @doneforaiur I don't think this has to do with disk usage because OP gets a file not found error. All of these errors should relate to those thrown by [`sem_open`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_open.3.html#top_of_page)

Comment: What is the actual code

Answer (score 0):

If your application has been running for several days, it's possible that some resources, such as file descriptors, have been exhausted. This can happen if the application is not properly releasing resources after they are no longer needed. Make sure you are closing files and releasing other resources correctly in your code. You can use context managers (with statements) or explicitly close resources using the appropriate methods.

Also, some operating systems impose limits on the number of semaphores or the maximum number of open files a process can have. You can check the system limits and adjust them if necessary.

Comment: Building from my comment on the question: if resources were exhausted then shouldn't why would the OP get a FileNotFound error? Wouldn't it correspond to one of the resource limit reached from [`sem_open`'s man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_open.3.html#top_of_page)?